# Using for loop to print out output

Tags: c, for-loop

My for loops seems not working properly. First number which tells me how many task do I want my program to do is `n`. When I input 1 or 2, it works, but when I input 3 and more, it starts to struggle. Every row has 3 numbers separated by a space as you can see in the code. I am not getting all outputs. Algorithm in this program works perfect so no problem there. 
Please ignore comments in the code. And sorry for my english.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int n;
int i;
int s;
int d;
int p;
int k;
int A;
int x;
int r[];
int koniec;

main()
{
   scanf("%d", &n);
   while( !(n >= 1 && n <=1000) )
   {
      //printf ( "max 1000 uloh min 1 \n");
      return 1;//scanf("%d", &n);
   }
   for( i=1; i < n; i++)
   {
      scanf("%d %d %d", &s, &p, &d);
      while((s < 1) || (s > 15000) || (p < 1) || (p > 4000) || (d < 1) || (d > 15000)) {
         //printf ("prekroceny limit \n");
         return 1; // scanf("%d %d %d", &s, &p, &d);
      }

      k = s / d;
      A = s - ( k * d );

      if ( A == 0 )
      {    
         r[i] == 0;
      }
      else
      {
         //s = k * d + A ;
         x = ( A * p ) / d ;
         r[i] = p - x ;
      }

   }

   for ( koniec = 0 ; koniec < i+1 ; koniec++ )
   {
      printf ( "%d", r[koniec] ) ;
      printf ( "\n");
   } 

   system("pause");
}
```

Example input so you can understand better:

```
4
5 4 4
6 100 3
500 5 1000
314 159 26
```

and output:

```
3
0
3
147
```

EDIT>

```
5
3434 234 2345
14455 345 12
134 145 1345
9242 2455 13455
83 34 133
```

output:

```
126
144
141
769
13
```

or something shorter>

input:

```
2
15000 1 1
1 4000 1
```

output:

```
0
0
```

Im getting return value 1 in both examples

My final code edit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;
int i;
int s;
int d;
int p;
int k;
int A;
int x;
int *r;
int koniec;

main()
{
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while( !(n >= 1 && n <=1000) )
    {
        return 0;//printf ( "max 1000 uloh min 1 \n");
        //scanf("%d", &n);
    }

    r = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d %d", &s, &p, &d);
        while((s < 1) || (s > 15000) || (p < 1) || (p > 4000) || (d < 1) || (d > 15000))
        {
            //printf ("prekroceny limit \n");
            return 0; //scanf("%d %d %d", &s, &p, &d);
        }

       k = s / d;
       A = s - ( k * d );

        if ( A == 0 )
        {    
            r[i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //s = k * d + A ; 
            x = ( A * p ) / d ;
            r[i] = p - x ;
        }
    }

    for ( koniec = 0 ; koniec < n ; koniec++ )
    {
         printf ( "%d", r[koniec] ) ;
         printf ( "\n");
    } 

    free(r);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: One thing that may help is giving your variables more useful names.  You can also declare them all on the same line if you want to save some space and make them more readable.  In addition, should we ignore all your commented out information?  I am unsure what your goal with this code is.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the help text about what and how to ask, here. And first of all format your code properly, this makes me dizzy.

Comment: Also you never seem to allocate memory for "int r[]".  Either statically allocated memory by place a number inside the brackets such as "int r[25]" or dynamically with malloc() function in stdlib.h.  (I'm guessing you will need malloc() seeing as you are iterating "n" times in a for loop via a dynamically scanned int.)

Comment: Another thing to note, you should probably change " for( i=1; i < n; i++)" to "for(i=0, < n; i++)".  Arrays start numbering with 0 in C.

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma how can I allocate memory using malloc? I have never used it before, Im a newbie. Can you show it to me please?

Comment: Also, this statement `r[i] == 0;` has no effect, you probably meant `r[i] = 0;`

Comment: Nice point Kninnung.  I missed that.  You also will likely have an Array Out Of Bounds problem (segmentation fault) on for ( koniec = 0 ; koniec < i+1 ; koniec++ ).  The "i+1" will be equal to "n" logically following your code which should be outside the bounds of an array length 'n'

Comment: I added input and output which I should get.

Comment: See my answer.  I got the code working with your inputs/outputs.  Chux answer should also work if you have a newer C99 or later compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [malloc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) to allocate memory dynamically.  (Also `#include stdlib.h`)

For instance, add the following line after the first while loop :

```
//Note - at the top, change int r[] to the below: 
int *r; //Instead of int r[]
//End note

while( !(n >= 1 && n <=1000) )
{
     printf ( "max 1000 uloh min 1 \n");
     scanf("%d", &n);
}

r = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int)); //Allocate "n" integers to your 'array r'
```

It should also be noted that once you are done using the array `r`, you must [free()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) this memory like so:

```
free(r);
```

In addition, there are some other coding problems:

1. Be sure `for( i=1; i < n; i++)` is what you want.  You use "i" to index your array, but arrays in C start from 0.  So it (likely) should read `for( i=0; i < n; i++)`.
2. `r[i] == 0;` is used falsely as an assignment.  Use a single `=` to assign a value to a variable.  Use the double equals `==` to compare two values.
3. `for ( koniec = 0 ; koniec < i+1 ; koniec++ )` will likely through an error.  Your `i` will be one less than `n` from the for-loop above it.  So trying to iterate to `i+1` or `n` will result in an array out of bounds problem -- aka a Segmentation Fault.

**Edit - This should do what you want:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;
int i;
int s;
int d;
int p;
int k;
int A;
int x;
int *r;
int koniec;

main()
{
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while( !(n >= 1 && n <=1000) )
    {
        //printf ( "max 1000 uloh min 1 \n");
        //scanf("%d", &n);
        return 1; 
    }

    r = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d %d", &s, &p, &d);
        while((s < 1) || (s > 15000) || (p < 1) || (p > 4000) || (d < 1) || (d > 15000))
        {
            //printf ("prekroceny limit \n");
            //scanf("%d %d %d", &s, &p, &d);
            return 1;
        }

       k = s / d;
       A = s - ( k * d );

        if ( A == 0 )
        {    
            r[i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            s = k * d + A ; //This line does nothing... Just so you know
            x = ( A * p ) / d ;
            r[i] = p - x ;
        }
    }

    for ( koniec = 0 ; koniec < n ; koniec++ )
    {
         printf ( "%d", r[koniec] ) ;
         printf ( "\n");
    } 

    free(r);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
4
5 4 4
6 100 3
500 5 1000
314 159 26
```

Output:

```
3
0
3
147
```

Comment: I have another problem but I dont know what is it. Because I have to upload this program to a competition and there is an online judge and it says that my program is wrong, what means that algorithm is wrong or something. Im 100% sure that the math part is okay, only thing Im worried about are loops and if conditions. But Im not sure about it. When I input higher numbers, numbers close to the top of the range in conditions, I get return value 1. However when I input lower numbers, return value is 0. What do you think?

Comment: Can you give me these numbers that you think are causing faulty input?  And what the expected output should be?  Programatically I don't think there are any issues without algorithm changes.  But I can take a look at it.

Comment: can I explain it to you in chat? its quite complicated

Comment: If I recall, you need at least 20 reputation to post in a chat.  You do not meet that requirement.  Just make an edit to your post below your original (like how I edited my post) and I'll address it in a second edit.

Comment: You can vote up my question and I will get about 20 reputation, but I added inputs and outputs so try it out. Expected output is same as when you use a calculator and follow math part in the code.

Comment: I get output of "126
144
131
769
13" using the new numbers.  The only difference is 131 vs 141.  Im thinking you just had a typo or math error.  Either way, the return value of Main() is somewhat irrelevant but you can (and probably should) return 0 after you pause.  I edited this one line in.  But it doesn't affect the validity of the algorithm.  Pre-C99, checking the return value of a non-void function that does not return a value is Undefined Behavior. -- And an upvote would not be enough.

Comment: so my range definition in while loop is okay right? cause every time I upload the program and it doesnt work I get penalty points...

Comment: Well you refuse to give any information regarding the algorithm itself, so I do not know if thats what you want.  But neither of the while loops will get executed with the example numbers you provided.  The "return 1" will not get executed. (Edited my example to reflect that you want those to return 1")

Comment: I added my final code so check return values in loops, cause it cant print out anything except output numbers. Well there is nothing in math what could be wrong, I mean Im getting correct numbers so it must be okay.

Comment: Given the expected input and output, the code works.  So unless you give me more of an explanation of what you want to work differently, I cannot help you.

Comment: I could give you more info but its a lot as I said, chat would be better, or some other kind of private messages if you agree.

Comment: I would guess if they are telling you your code is wrong, there is likely part of the algorithm that is incorrect.  And I cannot move it to chat because you only have 3 reputation points.

Comment: I just asked a judge about my program and he said he is getting mostly bad output and so algorithm might be bad he said. But Im wondering about my compiler, their online compiler says we should have compiler parameters like this: `-x c -lm '%1' -o binary` . Im using DevC++ and I dont know where to put it.

Comment: The newest information about the problem. He is getting correct output for the input I wrote /lower numbers/ but problem will be in different numbers, ...You have to see information about the task, what is it supposed to do.

Comment: How he compiles it shouldn't make any difference in the code execution.  And that means there must be a flaw in your algorithm design.  The math should work for all numbers if you wrote it correctly.  If you can post the algorithm or figure out what isn't doing what it should be, I can help you re-write it.  But you act as if I should magically know how to fix something that isn't broken given the information I have.  I fixed all the programming errors in your code and got YOUR algorithm to work with YOUR inputs... You gotta give me more if you want more help.

Comment: hey, I posted a question describing my situation here, please check  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736866/house-fortification-program)

Answer (score 0):

Allocate space for `r[]`.
Change assignment.
Change for loop range.

```
//int r[];
main() {
   scanf("%d", &n);

   // while( !(n >= 1 && n <=1000) )
   if (!(n >= 1 && n <=1000) )  {
      return 1;//scanf("%d", &n);
   }

   int r[n];  // allocate

   // for( i=1; i < n; i++)
   for( i=0; i < n; i++)  // Change range (@MrHappyAsthma)
     ...
     // r[i] == 0;   
     r[i] = 0;   //  change

     r[i] = p - x ;

   // for ( koniec = 0 ; koniec < i+1 ; koniec++ )
   for ( koniec = 0 ; koniec < n ; koniec++ )
```

Comment: This wont work in anything before C99 either... see here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Comment: What are your inputs?  What are your outputs?

Comment: Not only does he show his inputs above, but as someone learning C, he should really use malloc() and free()... You are leading him astray unless he has C99 and will use it exclusively.

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma Interesting to encourage programing style of 15 years ago with `malloc()` and cast its return value.  Further C11 compilers, aside form C99 ones, nicely handle variable length arrays.

Comment: Windows platforms no longer update their C compilers and it is not C99. Sure, there are many out there, but besides that, he will likely need to know how malloc() works in his C learning so why not learn it now and also prevent possible compiler errors since you haven't specified anything to him.  You think a new C learner knows their compiler version?  You also didn't address any of his other flaws (unless you've edited your answer since).

Comment: Windows is an OS not a manufacturer.  MS VS does well comply to C99.  On my windows machine, C99 runs just fine using other compilers.  As the post is not tagged Windows, its relevance is at best TBD.  Many of the flaws were address before your posts.

Comment: @user3294663 I also received "3  0 3 147" based on your updated input.  Without space for `r[]` the original post will fail.  If your compile is recent, one can use `r[n]` as shown above.  @MrHappyAsthma discusses using `malloc()/free()` and a 3rd alternative is to declare an array `r[1000]` - preferable in global space.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47238/discussion-between-mrhappyasthma-and-chux)